# Delete specific file version in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to figure it out with SP client methods. Right now I'm making Delete method which takes file Id and version and removes specific version of the file. The problem is when the version is the last actual version then SharePoint will actually remove the file completely with all its versions. What am I doing wrong?

```
using (var ctx = CreateClientContext())
{
    var fileItem = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentsFolder).GetItemById(fileId);
    ctx.Load(fileItem, item => item.File.Versions, item => item.File, item => item.File.UIVersionLabel);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if (string.Equals(fileItem.File.UIVersionLabel, fileVersion, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
    {
        fileItem.DeleteObject();
    }
    else
    {
        fileItem.File.Versions.First(fi => string.Equals(fi.VersionLabel,fileVersion,StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).DeleteObject();
    }
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not check your code. however, "the last version" and the file, they are only one file, they are the same. In the history list, the latest version just is a reference to the file. So if you delete the latest version, you delete the file and all of its versions too